# How to move over the login element to the top line in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with html on [this site](http://goo.gl/xLsBZf) and I have not been able to get the login element pulled up to the top line. I know I am not very descriptive, bit I just do not know what I got wrong. I have tried all sorts of examples from this site and they just do not work for me. Feel free to use google chrome developer tools to play with html and css.
Here is the code:

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-   =".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">St. Augustine School</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" style="text-align:center;" role="navigation">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-right">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="./getting-started">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./css">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./components">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./javascript">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

    </nav>
          <form class="navbar-form nav-center" method="post" action="/prossing.php">
    <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name = "username">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="signIn" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"     name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

<body>
</html>
```

well yes, this is just a cut from the site, but this is the navbar code.

Comment: first take note that body tag is not enclosed properly

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `float:left` for menu and `float:right` for login panel, here is the codes:

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" style="
text-align:center;
float: left;
" role="navigation">
...
<form class="navbar-form nav-center" method="post" action="/prossing.php" 
style="float: right;">
```

[image]

Comment: worked great!!! I love it how you guys just rush to the rescue when we have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, follow Drixson's advice and make sure all the tags are closed properly.

Then, I'd recommend you to place the login element and the nav-bar in the same container, each  one with a wrapper (floating left for the nav-bar and floating right for the login form).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twitter bootstrap I would suggest the solution of the bootstrap:

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse pull-left" style="text-align:center;" role="navigation">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-right">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="./getting-started">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./css">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./components">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./javascript">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>

<form class="navbar-form nav-center pull-right" method="post" action="/prossing.php">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="signIn">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>
```

So basically you have to add two classes first in your nav tag add "pull-left" class and second in your 'form' tag add "pull-right" class.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try the following code, here is the [fiddle](http://bootply.com/92167)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>          
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<form class="navbar-form nav-center" method="post" action="/prossing.php">`
To  `<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="/prossing.php">`

And put it in the navbar, like this;

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" style="text-align:center;" role="navigation">

<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="/prossing.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name="username">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="signIn">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
</form><ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-right"></nav>
```